# Consulta de articulos por categoria Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, controller

Buenas noches, estoy tratando de obtener las categorías y sus respectivos artículos. Quisiera que en la vista aparezca el nombre de la categoría como título y luego aparezcan cada uno de sus artículos:

Por ejemplo:

CÓMPUTO:
teclado, mouse, laptop

VEHÍCULOS:
camioneta, auto

...y así de cada categoría

Tengo el siguiente controlador pero no estoy seguro que sea así:

```js
$articulos=DB::table('articulo as art')
->join('categoria as cat','art.idcategoria','cat.idcategoria')
->select('cat.nombre as categoria','art.nombre as articulo')
->get();
return view('almacen.articulo.index',["articulos"=>$articulos]);
```

Y la vista sería:

```html
@foreach($articulos as $art)
 
 {{$art->categoria}}

  //Aqui otro @foreach???

@endforeach
```

Si alguien me podría ayudar... gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Ya probaste el otro foreach que muestras en un comentario del código?

Comment: No sé cómo estaría declarado ese foreach

Answer (score 2):

Debes usar un foreach dentro del foreach principal.
en tu Controlador

```
$categorias = Categoria::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->all();
```

en tu vista:

```
@foreach ($categorias as $categoria)
   {{ $categoria->nombre }}
   @foreach ($categoria->articulos as $articulos)
        {{ $articulos->nombre }}
   @foreach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Desde mi punto de vista creo que estás abordando el problema de la forma inversa, pues tu punto de referencia o inicial parecen ser las categorías:

Aunque no estoy de acuerdo con hacer consultas desde el controlador, pero para hacer más rápido el ejemplo, lo haré según tu estructura, asumiendo que tienes un modelo `Categoria` con la relación definida hacia otro modelo llamado `Articulo`:

```
$categorias = Categoria::with('articulos')->get();

return view('...', compact('categorias'));
```

En la vista (este código se puede mejorar y no está probado):

```
@foreach ($categorias as $categoria)

    {{ $categoria->nombre }}:

    @foreach ($categoria->articulos as $index => $articulo)

        @php $nombres[] = $articulo->nombre @endphp

    @endforeach

    @if (isset($nombres))
        {{ implode(', ', $nombres) }}
    @endif

@endforeach
```

Para que entiendas un poco más sobre las relaciones en Laravel, revisa: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships